# iCloud extension in Chrome asks for a code to be entered... where?

Tags: icloud, password, google-chrome

I hope this is the right sub...

I have installed iCloud on my Win11 PC, and downloaded the iCloud Passwords Extension for Chrome.

Every time I am asked for a password in Chrome, a box appears with a six-digit number that it says `Enter this verification code in the Chrome extension to enable iCloud Passwords.`

I cannot find any place to enter such a thing. The extension control in Chrome has no box for this, and does not ask for a number when I open it.

Does anyone know where this code is supposed to be entered?

Comment: I can only offer this - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/icloud-windows/icw76039ec0f/icloud - I've never used iCloud on Windows. On Mac, the number will pop up on any Mac/iPhone/iPad you own & an entry box will pop up over the window in the browser, like this… https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAAjJ.png

Comment: @Tetsujin - step 2 of the first section fails. There is simply no place I can find to type in the code.

Answer (score 1):

1. Pin the extension to your browser interface. Because iCloud extension will ask for two factor authentication every time you start your browser.
2. The iCloud app would alert you with a login and provides you the 6 digit auth code that Apple uses for all services.
3. Type it in. Probably since your extension is not pinned to the Chrome interface, the iCloud extension had no way to notifying you when to input the 6 digit code.